# How to scrape data from an obscure Windows 7 program?

Tags: database, screen-scraping, data-collection

I have the task of scraping the data from a piece of software written especially for a small charity. I have attached a screenshot (with identifying information blurred out) below:

[image: TERRA screenshot]

The data is in a table format, with too much information to contain in a single screen capture. What options do I have to 'scrape' the data? Ideally the method would preserve the table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may find it useful, I found several simple and relatively cheap data scraping tools. I went with ['Screen Scraping From Windows Applications Software'](https://www.sobolsoft.com/screenscraping/) from Sobolsoft, a Windows 7 compatible tool that exports data directly as an Excel file.